# Are there any bar-ends with a palm rest?

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars

One of my friend's bikes had these old and beaten alloy bar-ends that have some sort of palm rest integrated outwards of the handlebars (wing-like), such that your pinky-side palm area could rest on it and cradled at just the right angle without slippage (despite the 760mm bar width). They're branded "Turbo*lite*" (where the 'lite' is in courier new font) but they don't show up when googling them. I looked up "ergonomic bar ends" but most of them have the palm rests on the grips.

I was wondering if there are any manufactured nowadays where the rests are integrated to the bar-end itself.

EDIT: here's a vid of my friend's bar-ends
https://fs-01.cyberdrop.to/received_472530941083752-T93PfvIR.mp4

And a still from that video
[image]

Comment: I have never seen this, but as you note, there are lots of palm rests integrated with grips. There are also rests + grips + bar-end horns, but these horns are fairly short. I find the widest variety of these at aliexpress, and order several cheapos to try before settling on what works best.

Comment: Neat - thank you for adding that.  I've never seen one like it.  Is it possible that the "wing" was intended as a palm rest or was it to protect the "corner" ?   I can't see my hand's palm being there when using the bar-ends - it would be the "chopping-edge" or perhaps the "ulnar edge" or the "pinky/little finger edge"?     That part of the hand doesn't seem to have a common name.

Comment: I wonder if you're holding the corner more than the bar-end ?

Comment: @Criggie as the flatbars are wide, one's palms tend to slide outwards as you put weight forward. thus, the wings cradle the side of my palms rlly comfortably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There do appear to be several kinds of bar end, with some form of ergonomic grip though nothing identical to your example.

TurboLITE seems to have been entirely off-line despite being around in the late 90's and early 2000's   One of the constant themes is how light their parts are, being made from aluminium.

1. Zoom MTB bar ends - the narrowed part should allow a more relaxed and natural grip.  You could get something similar by using an increasing number of wraps of bartape and then top it off with one layer, or a length of heatshrink.
   [image: From https://www.evocycles.co.nz/Product/385666/product]
2. Ergon GP4 - not quite the same location of the palm support
   [image: From https://www.evocycles.co.nz/Product/396902/product]
3. Generic cheap rubber thing - this looks kinda rubbish, with only a rubber body and maybe one clamp.  Not expensive fortunately. [image: From https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001370614542.html]

---

4. Use normal round-profile bar ends but fit a pair of grips on top that have a palm support.  These are cheap enough, and as long as the barend is straight and the same diameter as your handlebars (22.2mm) the grips should go straight on.  The "wing" would be a little further forward than your example too.  Only issue might be if the bar-end is not long enough to get locking collars on both ends.
   [image: Generic photo]
5. We're in the 3D Printing age now.   Consider making a shape that feels right to your hand using clay or plastecine, or whittle something out of light balsa wood till it fits your hand.
   Then get it 3D Scanned.  This will give you a STL file that you can import into software, where you can manipulate it till there's a suitable hole for your bars or bar-end to go through.  Then add some way to clamp it down or perhaps just epoxy the whole hand-form to your bar-end and rely in its clamp.
    One feature is you can do the handform for the other hand by mirroring it.   Lastly print it, or get it printed in a suitable material which might be TPU if you want some squish, or ABS if you want firm toughness.  There are even carbon-fibre impregnated plastics.   
    You end up with grips that exactly match your body, the ultimate in personalisation.

Comment: This kind-of devolved into a product-rec, so I've added some more bodgy/DIY options too.

Comment: The Ergon GP* range are pretty good (I've got GP3 on my hybrid and some old [GP2](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/ergon-gp2-handlebar-grips) on my MTB - the larger the number, the longer the bar-end).  To me, using the palm rest and bar end together feels a little unnatural on the GP3, better on the GP2 but that's less of a bar end.  It may be possible to adjust them more suitably than I choose to

Comment: For 3D printing I'd probably take 3mm off the thickness where I want my hand to go, and glue down foam or gel.  You could even have mushroom-shaped voids and cast/spread silicone over the top of ABS, into the voids.  Or print very slightly undersize and wrap with EVA (drop) bar tape

Comment: I thought of the same thing about 3D printing. I was thinking of it as a last resort to append to preexisting bar-ends if I can't find a similar item.